# Multiple login-config for Java webapp

Tags: java, web-applications, authentication

I have a Java web application that has a website for user interactions. To authenticate users I configured the application via web.xml to use FORM-based authentication. Users are forwarded to a login page and everything is fine so far.

Now we are developing a desktop client (in C#) for this web application which accesses the application via RESTful web services. I implemented these services in the same web app as the web site and of course the caller of the web service should be authenticated too. But now I'm facing the problem, that whenever I call a web service the server is returning the login page's HTML as response.

I think it would be cool to be able to use another login-config for my REST service servlet (which would probably use BASIC authentication then).

Google didn't bring up much, but I can't believe I'm the first one being in such situation. So I would like to hear your thoughts and solutions.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only solution is have two apps for two clients having different login mechanisms. The application code should be seperated  and move it common app to which these apps with forward the requests.

Else, use your custom authentication.

Comment: Thank you. I already thought that this wouldn't be possible. So I think the best choice is to implement a custom authentication for the webservices...

Comment: 7 years later, is this still true? It seems it is

Answer (score 5):

I've solved this problem with a tomcat valve. The valve checks for the presence of an Authorization header, in which case, the header is used as credentials to authenticate the user, otherwise, the normal authentication method takes place.

Here is the code of the Valve:

```
package org.tastefuljava.tomcat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.apache.catalina.Realm;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase;

public class AutoBasicValve extends ValveBase {
    private static final String BASIC_PREFIX = "basic ";

    private String encoding = "UTF-8";

    public String getEncoding() {
        return encoding;
    }

    public void setEncoding(String encoding) {
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(Request request, Response response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        Realm realm = getContainer().getRealm();
        if (principal != null) {
            if (containerLog.isDebugEnabled()) {
                containerLog.debug(
                        "Already authenticated as: " + principal.getName());
            }
        } else if (realm == null) {
            if (containerLog.isDebugEnabled()) {
                containerLog.debug("No realm configured");
            }
        } else {
            String auth = request.getHeader("authorization");
            if (auth != null) {
                if (auth.toLowerCase().startsWith(BASIC_PREFIX)) {
                    auth = auth.substring(BASIC_PREFIX.length());
                    byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(auth);
                    auth = new String(bytes, encoding);
                    int ix = auth.indexOf(':');
                    if (ix >= 0) {
                        String username = auth.substring(0, ix);
                        String password = auth.substring(ix+1);
                        principal = realm.authenticate(username, password);
                        if (principal == null) {
                            containerLog.warn(
                                    "Could not authenticate " + username);
                        } else {
                            containerLog.info(
                                    "Authenticated as " + principal.getName());
                            request.setAuthType("BASIC");
                            request.setUserPrincipal(principal);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        getNext().invoke(request, response);
    }
}
```

You can use the valve by adding a <Valve> tag either in the server.xml file in your tomcat installation, or in the META-INF/context.xml file of your WebApp:

The project is on github: https://github.com/robbyn/mydsrealm

Comment: Wow, cool. If it was still 2011 I could use it :) But thanks for your work! I hope it helps someone.
Do you now if there's a similar thing for Glassfish?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and a couldn't find solution. 
You can define multiple authentication methods:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24485/thin_client.htm#SCPRG164
But:
Unfortunately, both FORM and BASIC cannot exist together in the list of auth-method values.

Comment: Is this applicable only to the WebLogic server or for other webservers like Wildfly too?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately login-config is not mapped like filters and servlets are so there is only one global to the webapp. That means you either need 2 webapps or if on JBoss, you can use the WebAuthentication class to inform the container of your app's programatic login. However, if you are using embedded jetty or other web servers, there is absolutely no way to support BASIC and FORM off together using web.xml. You would have to write a custom authentication service

However, you can convert to Apache Shiro and it will solve these issues in an amazingly well written, simple design. These steps will allow REST clients to use either BASIC auth on every page without a session cookie or login at /rest/login and receive a session. Browser clients can then use FORM auth

```
1) protect /login with "authc", set shiro.loginUrl to /login and host an HTML form at that location
2) protect /rest/login with "anon" and write a URL handler for POST with this code
    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(userName, password);
    token.setRememberMe(rememberMe);
    SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(token);
3) protect /rest/logout with "logout"
4) protect /rest/** with "noSessionCreation, authcBasic, rest"
```

Comment: Can you please point me to a link that shows how multiple login methods can be used in JBOSS.

Answer (score 0):

Me helped https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/SSLWithFORMFallback in combination with this [tomcat valve](https://github.com/encukou/pki/blob/master/base/server/tomcat7/src/com/netscape/cms/tomcat/SSLAuthenticatorWithFallback.java)  to allow SSL client certs and form and basic fallback authentication.

Best regards